# Redirect Route in React

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a component, that supposed to redirect `unlogged` users to home page "/".

#### The Problem is:

I don't why this component redirect users regardless of they are logged in or not...

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
  
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    console.log("ha")
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            props.auth ?
            <Component {...props} /> :
            <Redirect to="/" />
        )} />
    );
}
 
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state.firebase.auth.uid,"PR")
    return{
        auth: state.firebase.auth.uid
    }
}
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute)
```

**In console i get this:**
[image]

So `uid` exists in the rendering moment if I understand it well... :v

Comment: Your connect function will be executed from left to right, so `mapStateToProps ` will be called first (it print the uid), then `ProtectedRoute ` (print the text 'ha')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the issue in

```js
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    props.auth ?
    <Component {...props} /> :
    <Redirect to="/" />
)}/>
```

this `props` do not have the `auth`

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => {
    console.log("ha")
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            auth ?
            <Component {...props} /> :
            <Redirect to="/" />
        )} />
    );
}
```

Do like as above